# JWPlayer embedding from https (other domain) instead of Local File

Tags: javascript, html, video, jwplayer

I tried to use jwplayer with the following procedures:

1. File Name : test.html
   Content:

> ```
>  <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer-7.8.7/jwplayer.js"></script> 
> <script>jwplayer.key="encryptedKey";</script>
>   <div id="container">Loading the player ...</div> 
>
>   <script type="text/javascript"> 
>    jwplayer("container").setup({ 
>     file: "myFile.mp4", 
>     height: 400, 
>     width: 630, 
>     image: "preview.jpg", 
>     modes: [ { type: "html5" }, { type: "flash", src:myFile.mp4" }, { type: "download" } ] });
>   </script>
> ```

2. I already used the EncryptedKey with my own key, and it works.
3. But when I change from:

`file:myFile.mp4` and `src:myFile.mp4`

to

`file:http://openload.co/embed/h5t8uqOn9Os/Ozzy_2016.avi.mp4` and also `src:http://openload.co/embed/h5t8uqOn9Os/Ozzy_2016.avi.mp4`

why it is unable to load, the warning is : **"File couldn't be played"** ?

Comment: have you tried `src:www.openload.co/embed/h5t8uqOn9Os/Ozzy_2016.avi.mp4` insteadt of `http` yet?

Comment: tried both, but no good result came up! why is it because cross domain?  I wonder...